# How to handle large clipboard content from a Delphi application?

Tags: windows, delphi, clipboard

Users expect to be able to copy/paste **large** quantities of data from one instance of my Delphi application to the other. This could be hundreds of MB of pictures / documents... I find that preparing and retrieving the clipboard stream seems to be taking some time, so I was wondering if there could be a better solution.
Should I consider implementing some kind of client/server communication solution with the clipboard as a way to initiate communication ? If so what would be the recommended way of achieving the best performance ?
I've registered my own clipboard format so I do not care about compatibility with other software.

Comment: The performance bottleneck will be in your code that works with the clipboard data. Start by making that perform well. There is an issue with placing huge amounts of data on the clipboard, and that is that leaving it there can be a headache for the system. But a few hundred MB doesn't sound very much. You can have the copying app supply the data to the clipboard on demand (i.e. when it is pasted). Read about `WM_RENDERFORMAT`. But that won't change where your fundamental problem is.

Comment: You could have the producer app create a TCP or NamedPipe server and put the server info on the clipboard, and then the consumer app can read the info and open a connection to the server to download the data as needed.